# Axler: Prove $\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$ and $\mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\times \mathcal{L}(V_m,W)$ are isomorphic vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Suppose $V_1,...,V_m$ are vector spaces. Prove that $\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$ and $\mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\times \mathcal{L}(V_m,W)$ are isomorphic vector spaces.

There are other questions ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142951/mathcal-lv-1-times-cdots-times-v-m-w-approx-mathcal-lv-1-w-times-cd) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271380/can-i-use-dimension-to-prove-that-vector-spaces-are-isomorphic)) about this problem but they don't contain full proofs with all the intermediate details. Answers to those questions present hints or high-level discussions about approaches to these types of problems.

Initially, I thought all I had to do to solve this problem was show that the dimensions of the two vector spaces are the same. This is very easy to do.

There are two issues with this, however.

1. The problem does not assume $V_1,...,V_m$ are finite-dimensional.
2. After reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271380/can-i-use-dimension-to-prove-that-vector-spaces-are-isomorphic) I was convinced that it is important to actually find an isomorphism.

**Here is my attempt at solving this problem, which I found very tricky.**

Let $\alpha_{i,1},\alpha_{i,2},\ldots,\alpha_{i,\infty}$ be a basis for $\mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$.

Define the linear map $\Gamma: \mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\times\mathcal{L}(V_m,W)\to \mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$ by

$$\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m f_i$$

Let's prove that this $\Gamma$ is a bijection.

**First we show that it is injective.**

Suppose

$$\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=\Gamma(h_1,\ldots,h_m)\tag{1}$$

Then, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m f_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m h_i$.

Now, since $f_i\in\mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$ and $h_i\in\mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$ then

$$f_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}\alpha_{ij}$$

$$h_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty b_{ij}\alpha_{ij}$$

Then, from (1) we have

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty (a_{ij}-b_{ij})\alpha_{ij}=0$$

The $m$ inner sums represent $m$ vectors.

If any of them are non-zero, then they are linearly independent and the outer sum is non-zero since it is a linear combination of such vectors with non-zero coefficients. This case is ruled out.

The inner vectors must thus be zero vectors.

Thus,

$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty (a_{ij}-b_{ij})\alpha_{ij}=0$$

for $i=1,\ldots, m$ and so

$$a_{ij}=b_{ij}$$

for $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $j=1,\ldots,\infty$.

Thus, $f_i=h_i$ and $\Gamma$ is injective.

**Next, we show that $\Gamma$ is surjective.**

Let $g\in\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$.

Let $(v_1,\ldots,v_m)\in V_1\times\ldots\times V_m$ and

$$g(\alpha_{1j},0,\dots,0)=w_{1j}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$g(0,0,\dots,0,\alpha_{mj})=w_{mj}$$

for $j=1,\dots,\infty$.

Let $(v_1,\ldots,v_m)=\left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{1j}\alpha_{1j},\ldots \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{mj}\alpha_{mj} \right )\in(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m)$.

Then,

$$g(v_1,\dots, v_m)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}w_{ij}\tag{2}$$

We now show the existence of an $(f_1,...,f_m)\in\mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\mathcal{L}(V_m,W)$ such that $\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=g$.

Define $f_i\in \mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$ by

$$f_i(\alpha_{ij})=w_{ij}$$

for $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $j=1,\ldots,\infty$.

Then,

$$\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m f_i$$

and

$$\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)(v_1,\ldots,v_m)=\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)\left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{1j}\alpha_{1j},\ldots \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{mj}\alpha_{mj} \right )$$

$$=f_1\left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{1j}\alpha_{1j} \right )+\ldots+f_m\left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{mj}\alpha_{mj} \right )$$

$$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}w_{ij}\tag{3}$$

Since (2) and (3) are equal we have $\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=g$ and thus $\Gamma$ is surjective.

Since $\Gamma$ is a bijection between $\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$ and $\mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\times \mathcal{L}(V_m,W)$ then these vector spaces are isomorphic.

Comment: Quote from https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: *For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.*

Comment: There are multiple other questions about this particular problem. None of them seem to present a full proof with detailed steps. That is what I tried to do above.  The proof essentially defines a linear map $\Gamma$ and tries to show that it is bijective. This is the only step, and it has two substeps: show injection and surjection. If you want me to specify a more precise question, here it is: is the linear map $\Gamma$ defined above a bijection? Another question: is it ok to specify a basis with infinite elements for $\mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$?

Comment: The linked post seems to contain a slightly different proof. I try to construct a bijection from $\mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\times\mathcal{L}(V_m,W)$ to $\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m, W)$, the linked post gives a hint at how to construct a bijection from $\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m, W)$ to $\mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\times\mathcal{L}(V_m,W)$. Both ways accomplish the same goal, but my question is about this specific way of doing the proof. Also, above is an actual attempt at a full proof. The linked post is merely a hint without all the inner guts of the argument.

Comment: 1) I know what you mean $\Gamma$ to be, but it is not correctly defined. The $f_i$s cannot be added up because they don't have the same domain. 2) A base of $\mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$ can be more than countable. Anyway, using bases obscures the situation. The linked post proposes a clearer proof.

Comment: Suppose $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_2(x,y)=x+y$. Can I not write $g(x,y)=f_1(x)+f_2(x,y)$? I guess this doesn't apply though because we should consider each $f_i$ as a vector in a different vector space.

Comment: You can, but $f_1+f_2$ makes no sense. It is not $g$.

Comment: You are saying then that if $f_i\in L(V_i,W)$ and if I define $g=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m f_i$ this is not in $L(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$. When I wrote the proof, I did wonder about that part. I even initially defined intermediate functions $\phi_i:V_1\times\ldots\times V_m\to W$ as $\phi_i(v_1,...,v_m)=f_i(v_i)$. is this issue a complete deal breaker?

Comment: Not only is in not in $L(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$. It is not even *defined*. Similarly, "$\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty (a_{ij}-b_{ij})\alpha_{ij}$" makes no sense. Instead, your $\phi_i:=f_i\circ p_i$ is a good idea. And again: using bases is heavy and useless.

Comment: I provided [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4844402) in the linked post, to make it "contain full proofs with all the intermediate details".

Comment: Just to be sure then: though your other answer is nice and succinct, the original proposed proof (which is longer than necessary due to the use of bases) is nonetheless salvageable by using these intermediate linear maps? I did a quick sketch and it seems that this is the case. I will go through the whole proof again to try to make it correct with this alteration. Btw, one reason I think doing both proofs is nice at this stage is because it forces me to have to really know how bases work in the case of vector spaces of linear maps. But seeing your proof then opens up a whole other useful view.

Comment: I think that if you try to "salvage" your proof, it will become mine plus unhelpful use of bases. For instance for the injectivity of your $\Gamma$ (which, once correctly defined, becomes my $G$), proving that $$\sum_{i=1}^m(\sum_{j\in J_i} c_{ij}\alpha_{ij})\circ p_i=0\implies\sum_{j\in J_i}c_{ij}\alpha_{ij}=0\forall i=1,\ldots, m$$ requires proving that $$\sum_{i=1}^mf_i\circ p_i=0\implies f_i=0\forall i=1,\ldots, m.$$

Comment: As long as it is correct, I am happy for now. I have made the changes for the injectivity part in an answer below and will now work on the surjectivity part. Then I will carefully go over your other proof so I can try to do it that way in the future. Once I am done with that I will be even happier.

Answer (score 0):

After the discussion in the comments it is clear that the proposed proof has some incorrect steps. It seems the proof can be saved, however, by correcting these steps.

Here is an attempt to correct them.

Let $\alpha_{i,1},\alpha_{i,2},\ldots,\alpha_{i,\infty}$ be a basis for $\mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$.

Define the linear map $\Gamma: \mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\times\mathcal{L}(V_m,W)\to \mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$ by

$$\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \phi_{f_i}$$

where $\phi_{f_i}:V_1\times\ldots\times V_m\to W, (v_1,\ldots,v_m)\mapsto f_i(v_i)$.

Note that the above was the corrected portion. The sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\phi_{f_i}$ is a sum of linear maps in $\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$.

In the original proposed proof, we had the sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m f_i$ which was summing vectors (ie, functions) from different vector spaces, namely, $\mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$.

Next, note that a basis for $\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$ is

$$(\alpha_{1j},0,\ldots,0)$$
$$\ldots$$
$$(0,\ldots,0,\alpha_{mj})$$

for $j=1,\ldots,\infty$.

Now suppose $\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=\Gamma(h_1,\ldots,h_m)$.

Then, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\phi_{f_i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\phi_{h_i}$.

Since

$$\phi_{f_i}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{1j}(\alpha_{1j},0,\ldots,0)+\dots+\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{mj}(0,\ldots,0,\alpha_{mj})$$

$$\phi_{h_i}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty b_{1j}(\alpha_{1j},0,\ldots,0)+\dots+\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty b_{mj}(0,\ldots,0,\alpha_{mj})$$

then

$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty (a_{1j}-b_{1j})(\alpha_{1j},0,\ldots,0)+\dots+\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty (a_{mj}-b_{mj})(0,\ldots,0,\alpha_{mj})=0$$

and because of linear independence we have that for each $i=1,\ldots, m$ we have $a_{ij}=b_{ij}$ for all $j=1,\ldots,\infty$.

Thus, $\phi_{f_i}=\phi_{h_i}$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$.

Thus, $f_i=h_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$.

Therefore, $\Gamma$ is injective.

Next we prove that $\Gamma$ is surjective. Again we need to correct the same error that happened in the original injection portion of the proof.

Let $g\in\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$.

Let $(v_1,\ldots,v_m)\in V_1\times\ldots\times V_m$ and

$$g(\alpha_{1j},0,\dots,0)=w_{1j}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$g(0,0,\dots,0,\alpha_{mj})=w_{mj}$$

for $j=1,\dots,\infty$.

Let $(v_1,\ldots,v_m)=\left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{1j}\alpha_{1j},\ldots \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{mj}\alpha_{mj} \right )\in(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m)$.

Then,

$$g(v_1,\dots, v_m)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}w_{ij}\tag{2}$$

We now show the existence of an $(f_1,...,f_m)\in\mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\mathcal{L}(V_m,W)$ such that $\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=g$.

Define $f_i\in \mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$ by

$$f_i(\alpha_{ij})=w_{ij}$$

for $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $j=1,\ldots,\infty$.

Then (and this is the part that is corrected)

$$\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \phi_{f_i}$$

and

$$\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)(v_1,\ldots,v_m)=\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)\left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{1j}\alpha_{1j},\ldots \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{mj}\alpha_{mj} \right )$$

$$=\phi_{f_1}\left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{1j}\alpha_{1j} \right )+\ldots+\phi_{f_m}\left ( \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{mj}\alpha_{mj} \right )$$

$$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}w_{ij}\tag{3}$$

Since (2) and (3) are equal we have $\Gamma(f_1,\ldots,f_m)=g$ and thus $\Gamma$ is surjective.

Since $\Gamma$ is a bijection between $\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$ and $\mathcal{L}(V_1,W)\times\ldots\times \mathcal{L}(V_m,W)$ then these vector spaces are isomorphic.

Comment: It does not look correct to me. Why are you assuming that $\{\alpha_{i,n}|n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a basis for $\mathcal L(V_i,W)$? The vector space $\mathcal L(V_i,W)$ could have an uncountable basis, for instance, $\{\alpha_{i,x}|x\in\Bbb R\}$. Additionaly, the definition of a vector space does not gives us a rule for adding together infinitely many vectors. Thus, Eqs. like (2) and (3) does not make sense in general vector spaces.

Comment: Okay. Well, at this point in this Axler book, there hasn't really been an in depth treatment of infinite-dimensional vector spaces. So, I think I will come back to this problem when I learn more about the topic.

Comment: You will also need to define what you called $(\alpha_{1j},0,\ldots,0),\dots,(0,\ldots,0,\alpha_{mj})$ for $j=1,\ldots,\infty$ (or better, as [suggested previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4844371/timeline#comment_10319533): for respectively $j\in J_1,\dots, j\in J_m$), and to prove that it is "a basis for $\mathcal{L}(V_1\times\ldots\times V_m,W)$" (which might well lead you to some circular reasoning). Your proof of surjectivity also is flawed: now you seem to consider that $\alpha_{ij}\in V_i$, instead of $\in\mathcal{L}(V_i,W)$.

Answer (score 0):

It might simplify notation, etc to start with the case $n=2$ and proceed by induction on $n$.

In fact the direct sum of two vector spaces $U\oplus V$ which you are writing as $U\times V$ has the following *universal property*: Given two linear mappings $f\colon U\to W$ and $g\colon V\to W$, there is a unique linear mapping $h\colon U\oplus V\to W$ such that $h\circ i=f$ and $h\circ j=g$ where $i\colon U\to U\oplus V$ and $j\colon V\to U\oplus V$ are the two inclusion maps. It is common to set $h=f\oplus g$.

This makes the result for $n=2$ obvious and the general case follows.

Actually it even works for an infinite collection of $V_i$ where $\bigoplus_iV_i$ is the collection of sequences with only finitely many non-zero terms. It does not depend on finite dimensionality of the $V_i$ or $W$.

This sort of result works in any *abelian category* (such as modules over a ring) because the finite direct sum is the coproduct (and also the product); if arbitrary sized coproducts exist then the general case works.